# Azure Tables and SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-table-storage

Is there a way to view Azure Tables form SQL Server Management Studio or some similar tool?

Comment: Are you referring Table Storage or SQL Azure? It seems to me you are referring to Table Storage, but other people below focus on SQL Azure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You can install the Nov CTP of SQL Server 2008 . The SSMS supports connecting to Azure like connecting to any other on-premise database.
- You could also try this tool - http://hanssens.org/tools/sqlazuremanager/
- Another option is http://onlinedemo.cerebrata.com/sqlazureclient/ a tool by [Cerebrata](http://www.cerebrata.com/Products.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

As Joannes mentioned, it's unclear whether you are looking to browse SQL Azure or Azure Table Storage.

If it's SQL Azure you're asking about, then it's an easy answer: Yes. Simply go to your SQL Azure account online and grab the server name (.database.windows.net), and use that from SQL Server Management Studio when connecting to your database. Specify your admin username and password, and you're off and running.

If you're talking about viewing Azure Table storage, there are a few tools floating around. The most current seems to be the [Azure Storage Explorer](http://www.codeplex.com/azurestorageexplorer) on CodePlex. It'll let you view all of your Azure tables, and edit text blobs.